# Converting AVI videos to MP4 for browser compatibility using ffmpeg

Tags: python, ffmpeg

After processing the video while converting .avi video to .mp4 for browser compatibility getting below error:
[FFmpeg-user] Format avi detected only with low score of 1, misdetection possible!

Comment: nothing to worry of if it's working